# Lost CSR file but have the KEY file and CRT files

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I requested a SSL certificate by generating a key file then a .csr file. I submitted these to a provided and obtained the .crt files.

I then accidentally removed the .csr

I still have all the other files and can setup a https site. However will this be a problem down the line? Is there a way I can get the .csr file back? Will i ever need this again?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can generate a new CSR any time you need it, which is only at renewal or re-keying time.